# Proper way to type hint a private property in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, type-hinting

Following PEP 526 I'm wondering how to properly type hint an instance or class attribute that is decorated by a property. Do I type hint the underlying attribute or the name or the property?

Example of typing the attribute:

```
class Sample(object):
    _target_dir: Path

    @property
    def target_dir(self):
        pass
```

Or typing the property:

```
class Sample(object):
    target_dir: Path
```

Or some other way? Is it the same for instance and class variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should decorate the underlying function that the `@property` attribute is wrapping over:

```
class Sample:
    @property
    def target_dir(self) -> Path:
        return Path("/foo/bar")
```

If your property is wrapping around some underlying private attribute, it's up to you whether you want to annotate that or not. I recommend you do, so you can benefit from typechecking wherever you use that private attribute, but whatever types you add there are going to be unrelated to the type of the property itself.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it. The only reason I don't like this is that you lose the ability to set a default value along with the type hint. You must set a default value on the private attribute itself.